# How to stop execution of script, except without exiting interactive session

Tags: python, ipython

I like to paste hunks of code into an ipython window during development and debug.  I also have a situation where I want to stop execution if a condition happens:

```
if condition:
  <stop running>
```

Solutions like `sys.exit()` appear to exit all the way out of ipython back to a terminal prompt.  Is there another way?  At the moment I do this:

```
if condition:
  fjklsd;
```

Which gives an error and returns to the ipython prompt, but is pretty ugly too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can raise this exception `raise KeyboardInterrupt`